# NullReferenceException not caught in the catch Block (Array.Sort Method)

Tags: c#, exception, msdn

```
try
{
    Array.Sort(PokeArray, (x1, x2) => x1.Name.CompareTo(x2.Name));
}
catch (NullReferenceException R)
{
    throw R;
}
```

This is a simple line of code that sorts an array of objects I created, however; If there is a null value , it throws an exception.  The `try catch` block does not seem to work.

The exception occurs in this particular area `x1.Name.CompareTo(x2.Name)`, is the Catch block misplaced?

Thanks!

***Update:***
*Screenshot taken from comment below:*
[image]

Comment: If you want to catch an exception and rethrow it you should __always__ use `throw;` instead of `throw ex;` to avoid loosing the original stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I tried using thow only, it seems it still gives me the same error highlighting the same area which is this: "x1.Name.CompareTo(x2.Name)" saying that NullReferenceException was not caught, thanks!

Comment: Try catching an general exception and see if it works like `catch(Exception ex)` I know it's bad but just to see.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, looks fine. But you *are* rethrowing the exception after you have caught it; `Throw R` means that the exception is passed on to the block of code where your try-catch was called from initially.

```
try
{
    Array.Sort(PokeArray, (x1, x2) => x1.Name.CompareTo(x2.Name));
}
catch (NullReferenceException R)
{
    // throw R; // Remove this, and your exception will be "swallowed". 

    // Your should do something else here to handle the error!
}
```

**Update**

First of all, add your screen-shot link to the original post - it helps clarify your problem. :)

Secondly, your `try-catch` *does* catch the exception - just not while you are in debug mode. If you continue stepping after that line, you should be able to continue out of the try-catch clause, and you program should continue.

If your exception was not caught, it would have terminated the program.

> **PS**: Select `Debug` and `Exceptions..` from the main menu in VS, and make sure you don't have "Thrown" checked for any column - if you do, your program will pause and display any exception that occurs, instead of just "swallowing" them as it would otherwise.

**Let repeat this, just to be absolutely clear: This exception is only visible because the code is running in debug mode with exceptions viewing enabled.**

If the same code ran in production mode, the exception would be swallowed, just as the OP expects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it seems even if I don't rethrow it,the error persists.

Comment: Thanks but even that doesn't work, here's a screenshot if it helps: http://i497.photobucket.com/albums/rr333/Dialga1000/NullReferenceExeptionWeird.png

Comment: How does it persist? If it is a `NullReferenceException`, it _should_ get caught. If it does not, check that the exception really is of that type. That still won't fix the error in your original logic though - just "swallow" (hide) the error. You'd be better off fixing the original problem first: Removing (or ignoring) objects containing `null`.

Comment: Alright thanks, I have no idea how it still persists, take a look at this screenshot: http://i497.photobucket.com/albums/rr333/Dialga1000/NullReferenceExeptionWeird.png

Comment: The "PS" of this answer was key for me. VS 2019 go to menu Debug > Windows > Exception Settings. The problematic NullReferenceException is under C++ Exceptions

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the code won't throw `NullReferenceException` since the `NullReferenceException` is been swallowed by the default implementation of `Compare` method when you call `Array.Sort()`. And this exception is propagated as  `InvalidOperationException` down the line. This is why your `NullReferenceException` catch block skipped. You can reproduce the whole scenario with following simple example where I purposefully including null as collection element.

```
public class ReverseComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
     return y.CompareTo(x); //Here the logic will crash since trying to compare with   null value and hence throw NullReferenceException
    }
}

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] dinosaurs =
            {
               "Amargasaurus",
                null,
                "Mamenchisaurus",

            };

        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (string dinosaur in dinosaurs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dinosaur);
        }

        ReverseComparer rc = new ReverseComparer();

        Console.WriteLine("\nSort");
        try
        {
            Array.Sort(dinosaurs, rc); //Out from here the NullReferenceException propagated as InvalidOperationException.
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: using "Exception" in the catch block seems to work but now Names starting with any alphabet after "C" are gone, the last Name I entered in the data structure was "Chespin", all names after that are not populated in the ListBox that is populated through this array, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just make your code handle nulls better. E.g. if all of the values could be null, this should cover you:

```
if (PokeArray != null)
    Array.Sort(PokeArray, (x1, x2) =>
      string.Compare(x1 != null ? x1.Name : null, x2 != null ? x2.Name : null));
```

If you don't expect some of those values to ever be null, you can make the code simpler by removing the unnecessary null checks.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to remove the error however, the ListBox I populate using this array seems to empty now (Populating it with the "name" member), My data structure is such that I can guarantee no null values and even make it work, but I'm just curious what I would do if I didn't know when or where nulls could occur.